# Lower bound on size of largest conjugacy class of centreless perfect group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

Problem 20.30 in the [Kourovka Notebook](https://kourovka-notebook.org/) asks whether the maximum size
of a conjugacy class of a perfect and centreless finite group $G$ is bounded below
by $|G|^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Clearly, there cannot be a lower bound better than
$|G|^{\frac{2}{3}}$ (this can be seen when looking at the groups ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$
for $q \rightarrow \infty$). Computational investigations — I checked the
perfect groups of order $\leq 1342740$ — suggest that that bound does indeed hold.
However — since the question in the Kourovka Notebook only asks for the bound
$|G|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ — can the better bound be refuted?

Comment: Did you try other simple groups like $A_n$? $A_n$ does not work. But there are only a few infinite series of finite simple groups, and their conjugacy classes are known. If that will not work, try wreath products.

Comment: @markvs Simple groups are unlikely to be counterexamples. -- For ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, the asymptotics is just the given bound, and for other simple groups, even the bound $|G|^{\frac{3}{4}}$ seems to hold.

Comment: Then try wreath products.

Comment: Looks like the wreath products do not work: they are too large. I do not have other suggestions except to ask  the authors of the problem 
(Vaughan-Lee, the other author has died).

Comment: See Neumann, Peter M.; Vaughan-Lee, M. R.
An essay on BFC groups.
Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 35 (1977), no. 2, 213–237.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really answer the question, but Bob Guralnick and I proved in our 2006 paper on commuting probability that if $G$ is a finite group with $F(G) = 1$, then the number of conjugacy classes $k(G)$ is at most $|G|^{\frac{1}{2}}$, so that $G$ has  a conjugacy class of size at least $|G|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (our proof requires CFSG). The proof shows that we can't do much better in general than $k(G) \leq |G|^{0.41}$ when $F(G) = 1$, but it might be possible to do better for perfect groups. Later edit: well,direct products of copies of $A_{5}$ show that even for perfect centerless groups, we can't do much better than $k(G) \leq |G|^{0.39}$, but in those examples, it is still the case that the largest conjugacy class still has size greater than $|G|^{\frac{2}{3}}.$ But this does suggest that improving the $\frac{1}{2}$ bound to $\frac{2}{3}$ might be delicate.

Comment: [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2005.09.044) to the 2006 Guralnick-Robinson J. Algebra paper. Also, $F(G)$ is the Fitting subgroup, so $F(G)=1$ means $G$ has no nontrivial abelian normal subgroup.